# contents of .pdf, .doc and .docx not displaying in my tkinter text box

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I am trying to read the content of a text file, pdf file and ms word files. I am using the tkinter for my GUI. my lines of code are shown

```
import tkinter as tk
m = tk.Tk()

e1 = tk.Text(m)
e1.grid(column=0, row=1)

def uploadf():
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("text file","*.txt"),("pdf file","*.pdf"),("docx file","*.docx"), ("doc file","*.doc"),("all files","*.*")))
    filename2 = open(filename, "r")
    filen = []
    for line in filename2:
        filen.append(line)
    for x in filen:
        e1.insert("end",x)

btn = tk.Button(m, text= "Upload", command= uploadf)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
m.mainloop()
```

I am getting this error
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 662: character maps to** 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The text widget can only display text, it can't display .pdf, .doc, and .docx data.

Comment: so i guess i have to convert the .pdf, .doc and .docx to text first?

Comment: @thereal90: yes.